# div background with background-size: 100% < IE9

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I have a background image which is very big (2000x2000 px)

I also have a div with `width: 100%` and `dynamic height` which depends on the content inside it. How should I make this background fit to this div horizontally and repeat itself vertically in all IE browsers starting from IE7?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header/>

    <div class="content" style="width: 100%">
      Some dynamic contant from DB 
    </div>

    <footer/>
  </body>
</html>
```

For other browsers with css3 support I have used:

```
.content{
    background: url(../image.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

I saw some suggestions to use `filter` css property for IE browsers but it scales both horizontally and vertically so it is not what I want.

Any suggestions (css, js, hacks) how could I make it work are very welcome.

Comment: By using an image tag and setting it to 100% size.

Comment: but it won't repeat vertically. And you mean to use absolute positioning for that img?

Comment: but it is actually quite a good idea since my image is big its not very likely that I'll have a lot of content which exceeds the height and I could use only background colour for that 'overflow'. But I still would like to know how to do it with vertically repeating image.

Comment: it doesn't do what I want.